any way to play computer sound (movies, etc) to sonos speakers?
New to Ubuntu and was disappointed to realize Sonos does not support linux.  I loaded 'the unofficial sonos controller' (https://github.com/pascalopitz/unoffical-sonos-controller-for-linux) which allows me to connect to sonos speakers but only appears capable of playing from music services (spotify, etc).  Does anyone know of a way to modify the unofficial controller to include playing movies, etc... or a different player or code that directs computer to sonos via bluetooth?
Thanks for any help.
Ubuntu 24.04
Macbook Pro11,4

If you are getting sound via blue or wifi, then the hardwares and o/system are working. The app you installed is deprecated. From this, I assume you want to have a Linux GUI app in place of the Sonos app. afik, Linux has no such app yet, and Sonos refuses to write one. fyi, this is a user-forum, not a developer-forum.

Thanks for your response.  Yes, system is working wrt sound and yes, the installed app is deprecated.  Am looking for a Linux GUI app as you surmise but would also be happy with a mod to the app I loaded.  Apologies if this is the wrong forum for a question of this nature.  Do you know a more appropriate one by chance?  Thanks again.

Using noson CLI you can do this. For instance I have noson installed with flatpak and can stream my sound to my sonos speaker with the following commands in terminal:

flatpak run io.github.janbar.noson --cli --deviceurl=http://192.168.1.60:1400 Note that the deviceurl is the local ip of the speaker I want to connect to
then using the CLI I connect to the speaker I want by name e.g. connect Grot_Van_Sam
run playpulse
Finally go to your ubuntu settings and select pulse as
your output device.


The program mkchromecast will allow you to cast your music to Sonos devices.
